# Создание .exe файла из нескольких .py файлов с Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pytorch, pyqt6, vosk

Есть программа которая работает если запускать при помощи терминала, но при попытке сделать .exe файл, он компилируется но возникают ошибки связанные с torch

```
[7396] WARNING: file already exists but should not:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI73962\torch\_C.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
[7396] WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI73962\torch\_C_flatbuffer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
```

Лог выполнения pyinstaller:

```
D:\coding\python\artix_assistant> pyinstaller -F  interface.py
375 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.2
375 INFO: Python: 3.10.5
383 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
422 INFO: wrote D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\interface.spec
422 INFO: UPX is not available.
437 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\coding\\python\\artix_assistant']
1235 INFO: checking Analysis
1235 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1235 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1235 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1250 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
1266 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
7904 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
7905 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
9263 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
9453 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
9475 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
9536 INFO: Analyzing D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\interface.py
9901 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
9902 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
23781 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-gi.py'.
27168 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
40396 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
42002 INFO: Processing module hooks...
42002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
42002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
42002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sounddevice.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
42002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torch.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
42737 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
42862 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
42893 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42909 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42909 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42909 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43488 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43488 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43550 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43551 INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
43969 INFO: Trying determine the default backend as first importable candidate from the list: ['Qt5Agg', 'Gtk3Agg', 'TkAgg', 'WxAgg']
45876 INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['TkAgg']
45970 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...       
47830 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
48096 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
49831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
49847 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
50550 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
50566 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
50581 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
50597 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' because importing 'pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' raised: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'railroad'
51863 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
52643 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
52643 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
52643 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
52663 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt6.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
52878 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt6.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53050 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt6.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53284 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt6.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53534 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53769 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.io.matlab.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53784 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53784 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53784 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53784 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53847 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53847 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
312 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'setuptools._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' because importing 'setuptools._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' raised: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'railroad'
55879 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
56349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
56349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
57021 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
57021 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
57021 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
57021 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
57177 INFO: checking Tree
57177 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
57177 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
57271 INFO: checking Tree
57271 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
57271 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
57365 INFO: checking Tree
57365 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
57365 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
57521 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
57740 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
57865 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
57880 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
57896 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
57896 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
57896 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'        
57896 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
57912 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
57912 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
57912 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt6.py'
57959 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:156: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
4174 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1.dll dependency of C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
4252 INFO: Cannot get manifest resource from non-PE file C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_sounddevice_data\portaudio-binaries\README.md
4252 WARNING: Cannot get binary dependencies for file: C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_sounddevice_data\portaudio-binaries\README.md
4252 WARNING:   Reason: 'DOS Header magic not found.'
5550 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\_C_flatbuffer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
5550 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
64635 INFO: Looking for eggs
64635 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll
64635 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
64666 INFO: Warnings written to D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\build\interface\warn-interface.txt
65057 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\build\interface\xref-interface.html
65666 INFO: checking PYZ
65666 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
65666 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\build\interface\PYZ-00.pyz
68824 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\build\interface\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
68933 INFO: checking PKG
68933 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
68933 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) interface.pkg
200906 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) interface.pkg completed successfully.
201328 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
201328 INFO: checking EXE
201328 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
201328 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
201328 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\dist\interface.exe.notanexecutable
201406 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
201406 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\artix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
201469 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
201469 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
201484 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
201484 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
201484 INFO: Updating manifest in D:\coding\python\artix_assistant\dist\interface.exe.notanexecutable
201547 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
201562 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
201797 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
206831 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

как можно решить эту проблему с pyinstaller или может нужно воспользоваться чем-то другим для этой задачи?

Comment: WARNING Предупреждение а не ошибка.

Comment: но из-за этого программа не запускается

Comment: Где доказательства?

Comment: [7396] WARNING: file already exists but should not:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI73962\torch\_C.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
[7396] WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\artix\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI73962\torch\_C_flatbuffer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd это то, что появляется в консоли при запуске, и программа закрывается

Comment: Попробуйте собрать на python37

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712154/pyinstaller-warning-lib-not-found

Comment: Без вот  этого torch_C_flatbuffer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd работать не будет, ваша задача сводится к тому чтобы pyinstaller упаковал эти либы архив